# Having a issue with Shared Preferences

Tags: android, button, calendar, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save something that enters the editText with sharedPreferences, and display the bigger number that the person wrote in a TextView, the smaller number in other TextView, and finally the somatory of all the numbers that the person gave and divide the result by the number of numbers they wrote(I'm not english, I think the name of this is averaging?, but you get the idea...). There's something wrong in the button code, and I can't find what, I asked my professor and he said that I misplaced the commit, I think I fixed that, but still doesnt work. This is my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences sh;
float niligo,xukitana,garbodoro,guzzlorodo;
TextView pesbig;
TextView pessmall;
TextView pesmedio;
EditText peso;
int xa,xu,xo;
int maior,menor,media,total,quantidade;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    peso = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    pesbig = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.View1);
    pessmall = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.View2);
    pesmedio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.View3);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR); //this is me trying to lock the edit text so the person can't give more than one number a day.

    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int i = 0;
            i++;
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
            xa = Integer.parseInt(peso.getText().toString());
            ed.putInt("pes", xa);
            xu = prefs.getInt("pes",xa);
            quantidade = i;
            total = xa+xu;
            media = total/quantidade;


            if (xu > xa){
                ed.putInt("pesmai", xa);
                niligo = prefs.getFloat("pesmai",xa);
                pesbig.setText(prefs.getString("pesmai", null));

            }
            else if (xu < xa){
                ed.putInt("pesmen", xa);
                xukitana = prefs.getFloat("pesmen",xa);
                pessmall.setText(prefs.getString("pesmen", null));
            }

                pesmedio.setText(String.valueOf(media));
                ed.commit();
```

Error logs

When the EditText is empty:

```
10-17 20:09:22.816 10133-10133/com.omfgdogs.omfgpeso E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.omfgdogs.omfgpeso, PID: 10133
                                                                   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
                                                                       at com.omfgdogs.omfgpeso.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4496)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18603)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When the EditText has a number:

```
10-17 20:12:15.056 12673-12673/com.omfgdogs.omfgpeso E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.omfgdogs.omfgpeso, PID: 12673
                                                                   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
                                                                       at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getFloat(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:254)
                                                                       at com.omfgdogs.omfgpeso.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:63)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4496)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18603)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

~The lines are the ones I quoted down here~

Comment: So... why do you think there's something wrong with it?

Comment: The app crashes when I press the button

Comment: And what error do you get in the logcat? Don't forget to explain where the line number is pointing to if you have a stack trace.

Comment: Invalid int: "" ---- line: xa = Integer.parseInt(peso.getText().toString());

Comment: So the text in that EditText is an empty string, which cannot be parsed as an integer.  Check if it's empty before parsing it.

Comment: When I type something the error goes to "FATAL EXCEPTION: main" line --- xukitana = prefs.getFloat("pesmen",xa);